# GeoServer crop Coverage WPS with Image Mosaic

Tags: geoserver, wps, image-mosaic, clip

I'm running GeoServer 2.7.4 und Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. I got several areas covered by aerial images. Now I want to offer these areas as Image Mosaics and give users the ability to select a subset by vector geometry and download it afterwards by executing a WPS with ras:CropCoverage.

I have tested a process in the WPS Request Builder with a single GeoTIFF and a vector layer as input. This works great. When I change the input from single GeoTIFF to Image Mosaic layer the process won't be executed and throws an error.

The vector layer for clipping and the image mosaic both use EPSG:31466 as native CRS

[image]

**Here is the output when I run the process**

```
    <wps:ExecuteResponse xml:lang="en" service="WPS" serviceInstance="http://192.168.1.38:8080/geoserver/ows?" version="1.0.0"><wps:Process wps:processVersion="1.0.0"><ows:Identifier>ras:CropCoverage</ows:Identifier><ows:Title>Crop Coverage</ows:Title><ows:Abstract>Returns the portion of a raster bounded by a given geometry.</ows:Abstract></wps:Process><wps:Status creationTime="2015-11-27T12:25:48.218Z"><wps:ProcessFailed><ows:ExceptionReport version="1.1.0"><ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode"><ows:ExceptionText>Failed to retrieve value for input coverage
org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No authority was defined for code &quot;UNNAMED&quot;. Did you forget &quot;AUTHORITY:NUMBER&quot;?
No authority was defined for code &quot;UNNAMED&quot;. Did you forget &quot;AUTHORITY:NUMBER&quot;?</ows:ExceptionText></ows:Exception></ows:ExceptionReport></wps:ProcessFailed></wps:Status></wps:ExecuteResponse>
```

**Here are the XML process parameters and results**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>ras:CropCoverage</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>coverage</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wcs:GetCoverage service="WCS" version="1.1.1">
            <ows:Identifier>DOP:TIFF</ows:Identifier>
            <wcs:DomainSubset>
              <ows:BoundingBox crs="unnamed">
                <ows:LowerCorner>2576000.0 5696000.0</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>2594000.0 5712000.0</ows:UpperCorner>
              </ows:BoundingBox>
            </wcs:DomainSubset>
            <wcs:Output format="image/tiff"/>
          </wcs:GetCoverage>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>cropShape</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wps" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS">
            <ows:Identifier>gs:CollectGeometries</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:DataInputs>
              <wps:Input>
                <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
                <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
                  <wps:Body>
                    <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2" xmlns:DOP="DOP">
                      <wfs:Query typeName="DOP:clipper"/>
                    </wfs:GetFeature>
                  </wps:Body>
                </wps:Reference>
              </wps:Input>
            </wps:DataInputs>
            <wps:ResponseForm>
              <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1">
                <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
              </wps:RawDataOutput>
            </wps:ResponseForm>
          </wps:Execute>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="image/tiff">
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

I think the problem is that in the WPS Describe process of ras:CropCoverage there is only GeoTIFF, base64 and arcgrid allowed as the process input. My question now is if anybody knows how to crop Image Mosaic Layers with WPS in GeoServer or if there is any other way to achieve this.

I also tried to execute a WCS request using the WCS Request editor delievered with GeoServer. Params and results of the raster request are in the screenshots below. The generation of the request in XML does not work.

[image]

Comment: does your image mosaic have an SRS defined?

Comment: I edited the question. All datasets involved use EPSG:31466

Comment: You only show the tif and vector, the error message definitely suggests the mosaic has an SRS of unamed.

Comment: I'm sorry for my initial naming conventions. The TIFF Layer was the Image Mosaic which uses EPSG:31466 as shown in the edit layer section. Now it should be clear in the screenshot. You're indeed right that the process XML does not contain any crs information which I can not explain. What could I do to modify the XML request?

Comment: could you just use a WCS request?

Comment: see the results in my question

Comment: It looks like WCS is disabled?

Comment: WCS is enabled. If I choose my Single GeoTIFF in the WCS request builder I'm able to download the dataset GeoTIFF

Comment: HI, there is nothing data source specific in the processes, they can accept any raster layer configured in Geoserver. But there might be an issue specific to your configuration, like, for example, maybe the native CRS of the mosaic could not be recognized? I'd suggest you to move the discussion to the geoserver users list, this site is great for questions, pretty poor for debugging...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this one may be closed. It was indeed a problem with the native CRS. I reprojected the files using QGIS and afterwards I was able to  execute the WPS and get the result as a TIFF.